# Pass easing function as variable in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've been looking for some time now..
Is is possible to pass easing function as variable in AS3?

eg.

```
TweenLite.to(mcDelimiter, resizeTween, { x:(stageWidthHalf-(initStageWidthHalf-mcDelimiteri_X)), ease:Elastic.easeOut } );  

TweenLite.to(mcBody, resizeTween, { x:(stageWidthHalf-(initStageWidthHalf-mcBody_X)), ease:Elastic.easeOut } );
```

... now if I at some point want to change "Elastic.easeOut" to something else I would have to change it at multiple parts of the code..
Can it be done so I just pass it as a variable and then if I want to change it, do it only on one place?

EDIT: ...also, 
can for eg. `if(currentFrame == "FrameLabel")` somehow be done? ..meaning, can I pass the currentFrame label name as a variable?

Thanks in advance for anwsers,

Andrej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass around a reference to a function in ActionScript, just as you would with any other object. For instance ( pseudo code ):

```
var equation:Function;
equation = Elastic.easeInOutSine;

TweenLite.to(mcDelimiter, resizeTween, { x:(stageWidthHalf-(initStageWidthHalf-mcDelimiteri_X)), ease: equation } );
```

All you need to do is create a variable to act as a reference to the easing function. You could wrap the call to TweenLite in another function and pass the easing variable to it like so:

```
public function doTween( equation:Function ):void 
{
     TweenLite.to(mcDelimiter, resizeTween, { x:(stageWidthHalf-(initStageWidthHalf-mcDelimiteri_X)), ease: equation } );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks!!
btw: if someone else has the same problem, using "currentLabel" instead of currentFrame gets the current frames name... duh! :)